# How to count ID in child table?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to count `StandardID` in two detail tables (`StandardCourses` and `StandardPosts`).
I wrote this code

```
Select es.StandardID, count(esc.StandardCourseID) as CourseIDCount,
       count(esp.StandardPostID) as PostIDCount
 from EduStandards as es 
      left join EduStandardCourses as esc on es.StandardID = esc.StandardID
      left join EduStandardPosts as esp on es.StandardID = esp.StandardID
 group by es.StandardID
```

but it return false result:

```
StandardID | CourseID | PostID
-----------+----------+--------
     3     |     2    |    2
     4     |     1    |    1 
     5     |     1    |    0
     9     |     1    |    0
```

While it must return:

```
StandardID | CourseID | PostID
-----------+----------+--------
     3     |     1    |    2
     4     |     1    |    1
     5     |     1    |    0
     9     |     1    |    0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `Distinct` to the `count`

```
Select es.StandardID, count(Distinct esc.StandardCourseID) as CourseIDCount,
       count(esp.StandardPostID) as PostIDCount
 from EduStandards as es 
      left join EduStandardCourses as esc on es.StandardID = esc.StandardID
      left join EduStandardPosts as esp on es.StandardID = esp.StandardID
 group by es.StandardID
```

It is a wild guess that a `StandardCourseID` can have more than one `StandardPostID`. We can write more appropriate answer if there is sample data of those three tables

Or `Count` the child table first

```
SELECT es.standardid, 
       esp.CourseIDCount, 
       Count(esp.standardpostid)            AS PostIDCount 
FROM   edustandards AS es 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT Count(StandardCourseID) AS CourseIDCount, 
                         standardid 
                  FROM   edustandardcourses 
                  GROUP  BY standardid) AS esc 
              ON es.standardid = esc.standardid 
       LEFT JOIN edustandardposts AS esp 
              ON es.standardid = esp.standardid 
GROUP  BY es.standardid
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be required to get the count first to get rid of duplicates from both the left joins.

```
SELECT es.standardid, 
esc.CourseIDCount, 
esp.PostIDCount
FROM   edustandards AS es 
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT standardid, Count(StandardCourseID) AS CourseIDCount, 
    FROM   edustandardcourses
    GROUP  BY standardid
) AS esc 
ON es.standardid = esc.standardid

LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT standardid, Count(StandardPostID) AS PostIDCount, 
    FROM   edustandardposts
    GROUP  BY standardid
) AS esp 
ON es.standardid = esp.standardid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try query like this

```
;WITH CTE_edustandardcourses AS 
(
    SELECT standardid, Count(StandardCourseID) AS StandardCourseCount, 
    FROM   edustandardcourses
    GROUP  BY standardid
), CTE_edustandardposts AS
(
    SELECT standardid, Count(StandardPostID) AS StandardPostCount, 
    FROM   edustandardposts
    GROUP  BY standardid
)
SELECT es.standardid, 
SC.StandardCourseCount AS CourseID, 
SP.StandardPostCount   AS PostID
FROM   edustandards AS es 
LEFT JOIN CTE_edustandardcourses SC
ON es.standardid = SC.standardid
LEFT JOIN CTE_edustandardposts SP 
ON es.standardid = SP.standardid
```